# Sending email using java app

Tags: java, email

Why can't this code send email?  There are no errors, it just doesn't send.

```
package tips.mails;

import java.util.Properties;


import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;



public class SendMail {
private String from;
private String to;
private String subject;
private String text;

public SendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String text){
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.text = text;
}

public void send(){

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    InternetAddress fromAddress = null;
    InternetAddress toAddress = null;
    try {
        fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
        toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        simpleMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
        simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
        simpleMessage.setSubject(subject);
        simpleMessage.setText(text);

        Transport.send(simpleMessage);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        new SendMail("source", "dist","Subject", "Test Message!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever actually call `send()`?

Comment: If there's no exception, what happens on the mail server?  Have you debugged that at all?  Point this at a mail server you can control (something like Smtp4Dev or similar) and watch the mail server logs.  Maybe the server is rejecting it?  Maybe the recipient is marking it as spam?  If the nature of the problem is "I run this code and my Inbox doesn't get a new message" then there are MANY things that can go wrong in between, most of which have nothing to do with the code.

Comment: What is your send() method there for??.. is it not meant to inkoved??:P

Answer (score 3):

You instantiate a `SendMail` object and do nothing with it. Maybe you should also execute your `send()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call send. Try this

```
   new SendMail("source", "dist","Subject", "Test Message!!!").send();
```

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1270)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
 at tips.mails.SendMail.send(SendMail.java:53)
 at tips.mails.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:63)

Comment: its run just with me.com server with port 25 How can make it run for all servers

Comment: But now it does not run, Error:530 5.7.0 No STARTTLS command has been given.